# What did renegading mean in Dua Lipa's Levitating

Tags: meaning-in-context

Dua Lipa uses "renegading" in her Levitating song.

> You want me, I want you, baby
> My sugarboo, I'm levitating
> The Milky Way, we're **renegading**
> Yeah, yeah, yeah, yeah, yeah

The word's obvious meaning of leaving a religion, doesn't seem to fit in the song. What if the meaning of "renegading" in the song?
Here are the relics:
https://genius.com/Dua-lipa-levitating-lyrics

Comment: It doesn't just have to be a religion — it can be any sort of organisation, group or even country. She's running away from the Earth to go and dance in the stars.

Comment: @BeginTheBeguine Surprisingly to me, historically the word applied to Spanish converts to Islam. Even my (admittedly somewhat aging) dictionary went for this usage.

Answer (score 1):

Partly it's just a rhyme for "levitating".

Literally a renegade is "a person who behaves in a rebelliously unconventional manner" (Ox languages).  While it originally meant a "traitor" (or in even older use, an apostate), those meanings are now not so common, especially among younger speakers. Being a "renegade" has a positive sense.

So it means "We're being unconventional and rebelling", (as teenagers often try to do).

As the editor on Genius writes:

> It might mean that they plan to break with traditions (for example traditional courtship) and begin a new exciting love.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with any historical ideas, or any dictionary definitions.

"Renegade" is a TikTok dance. A [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tc_tGAgEWcQ) for reference.